Issue with Sentiment Analysis in Amazon Comprehend Analysis Job
I used Amazon Comprehend for sentiment analysis and successfully analyzed a conversation using Real-time analysis. However, when I upload the same conversation as a text file to an S3 bucket and create an analysis job in the Amazon Comprehend Analysis Jobs section, I don't get any sentiment analysis results.
Here are the details of my setup:

The text file is in text format.
I ensured that the analysis job was created successfully, and the file was processed.
I can see the job completed without errors
I have provided the correct S3 bucket permissions and IAM roles.

Am I missing any specific configuration or steps required to get sentiment analysis in an analysis job?
